# Why does this c++ boolean return false

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was trying to write a loop that loops from back to forth in a string. But the loop doesn't work and it turns out one of the comparison does not work correctly.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    string a = "12";
    int i = 0;
    int index = a.size() - i - 1;

    std::cout << (a.size() - i - 1 > -1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (index > -1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first print was 0 and the second print was 1. Why does the first print printed a false?

Comment: Something something `unsigned` something.

Comment: An `int` with value `-1` converted to an unsigned type always produces the largest value that type can hold.